# Python mapping debugging

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have 50+ csv files I want to standardize to have the same header. I'm going through and basically generating a dictionary of each file's headers to a master list of headers I want to output eg BusinessName-> LastOrBusinessName. Or if I'm not interested in keeping the field I'll map it to skip.

So a little something like this

```
npi_num,skip
provider_type,providertype
specialty,providertype
speciality,providertype
exclusion_effective_date,exclusiondate
actiondate,exclusiondate
sanctiondate,exclusiondate #NOTE MULTIPLE mappings per field to handle different files
businessname,businessname
firstname,firstname
lastname,lastname
npi_4digits,skip
exclusionstatemedicaid,exclusionstatemedicaid
postdate,skip # full dictionary is ~300 lines this is a small sample.
```

Next I'm reading files with python and looking at the header then renaming headers using my list. This is where I have issues. For my function I'm passing in the dictionary (above) as well as the headers for the input.

```py
def map_headers(mapping, input_fields):
    output_fields = {}
    for field in input_fields:
        if field in mapping:
            if mapping[field]['Mapped To'].lower() != 'skip':
                output_fields[field] = mapping[field]['Mapped To']
        else:
            output_fields[field] = field

    # Make sure all output fields are present in the header
    for output_field in output_fields.values():
        if output_field not in headers: #I want a empty field even if none of the data matches so all my files have the same headers
            headers.append(output_field) 


    # Map the input fields to the output fields
    output_mapping = {}
    for output_field, input_field in output_fields.items():
        if input_field in headers:
            output_mapping[output_field] = input_field
        else:
            output_mapping[output_field] = ''
    return headers, output_mapping
```

Then I have a bunch of code to basically print the data into a new csv file.

So I'm expecting a set header for every file after I process (as well as keeping the data in that column)

```
rowid,exclusiondate,lastnameorbusinessname,firstname,providertype,exclusionauthority,exclusionreason,lastname,businessname,exclusionstatemedicaid
```

except depending on the file I'm not getting the same header.
I'm not sure how to begin to make sure its in the right order either (I want it to match exactly that) but at this point I'll settle for figuring out why my dictionary isn't mapping the fields correctly.

Sample input file:

```
rowid,lastnameorbusinessname,firstname,npi,begindate,reason,lastname,businessname,npi_4digits,exclusionstatemedicaid
1,Bhullar-Ball,Ramneet,1255336244.0,9/17/2015,Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare patients,Bhullar-Ball,,6244,TN
2,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",,1407898018.0,9/17/2015,Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare patients,,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",8018,TN
3,Clabough,Kenneth,1043631401.0,10/30/2015,Failure to disclose required information,Clabough,,1401,TN
```

Desired output:

```
rowid,exclusiondate,lastnameorbusinessname,firstname,providertype,exclusionauthority,exclusionreason,lastname,businessname,exclusionstatemedicaid
```

So there are 3 lists. 1 is the input list (eg the sample header above). 2 the mapping list for the above file it would be
rowid->rowid,lastnameorbusinessname->lastnameorbusinessname,firstname->firstname,npi->skip,begindate->exclusiondate,reason->exclusionreason,lastname->lastname,businessname->businessname,npi_4digits->skip,exclusionstatemedicaid->exclusionstatemedicaid
3. the output header list is the standardized header I want every file to have. (refer to desired output)

so basically it would rename begindate to exclusiondate and reason to exclusion reason and drop the npi/npi_4 columns and leave everything else the same.

What I actually got as output

```
rowid,lastnameorbusinessname,firstname,npi,begindate,reason,lastname,businessname,npi_4digits,exclusionstatemedicaid
1,Bhullar-Ball,Ramneet,1255336244.0,9/17/2015,Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare patients,Bhullar-Ball,,6244,TN
2,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",,1407898018.0,9/17/2015,Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare patients,,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",8018,TN
3,Clabough,Kenneth,1043631401.0,10/30/2015,Failure to disclose required information,Clabough,,1401,TN
```

For clarity about what is right/wrong with the output: begindate is mapped to exclusiondate (but it wasn't renamed) , npi_4digits was supposed to be dropped. npi was correctly dropped. The headers are out of order still.

This is what's in the dictionary:

```
npi,skip
npi_4digits,skip
begindate,exclusiondate
```

Comment: I'm getting lost in all the dictionaries and lists, but `if input_field in headers:` doesn't seem right. Can you add a couple of sample input files and the desired output?

Comment: I've edited the question to show a sample file but basically the 3 lists are input (what I have) output(what I want) and mapping (what needs to change but also things that aren't changing)

Comment: Please format your question readably so I don't have to keep doing it for you.

Comment: sorry, it's hard to follow along, seems like you would like to standardize the header names across files. I think [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) would be a good choice here.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want to do. Problem is pandas doesn't do that for me or at least from the documentation I don't see how it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another try.  there are two bits in there I used as a test to inject a random key/value that has multiple mappings into the small sample you gave.

```
from pprint import pp
from random import choice
import csv

includes = {
    'npi': 'skip',
    'rowid': 'rowid',
    'begindate': 'exclusiondate',
    'exclusion_effective_date': 'exclusiondate',
    'actiondate': 'exclusiondate',
    'sanctiondate': 'exclusiondate',
    'lastnameorbusinessname': 'lastnameorbusinessname',
    'firstname': 'firstname',
    'providertype': 'providertype',
    'provider_type': 'providertype',
    'specialty': 'providertype',
    'speciality': 'providertype',
    'exclusionauthority': 'exclusionauthority',
    'exclusionreason': 'exclusionreason',
    'reason': 'exclusionreason',
    'lastname': 'lastname',
    'businessname': 'businessname',
    'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'exclusionstatemedicaid',
    'npi_4digits': 'skip',
    'postdate': 'skip',
    }
result = []

with open('data.csv', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        curr_row = {}
        ###
        test = choice(['providertype', 'provider_type', 'specialty', 'speciality'])
        row.update({test: f'mapped from {test}'})
        ###
        for key, val in includes.items():
            if val == 'skip': continue
            try: curr_row[val] = row[key]
            except KeyError:
                curr_row[val] = curr_row.get(val)
        result.append(curr_row)
        pp(curr_row)
```

output:

```
{'rowid': '1',
 'exclusiondate': '9/17/2015',
 'lastnameorbusinessname': 'Bhullar-Ball',
 'firstname': 'Ramneet',
 'providertype': 'mapped from provider_type',
 'exclusionauthority': None,
 'exclusionreason': 'Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare '
                    'patients',
 'lastname': 'Bhullar-Ball',
 'businessname': '',
 'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'TN'}
{'rowid': '2',
 'exclusiondate': '9/17/2015',
 'lastnameorbusinessname': 'Cumberland Neurology, LLC',
 'firstname': '',
 'providertype': 'mapped from providertype',
 'exclusionauthority': None,
 'exclusionreason': 'Failure to respond to requests for records on Tenncare '
                    'patients',
 'lastname': '',
 'businessname': 'Cumberland Neurology, LLC',
 'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'TN'}
{'rowid': '3',
 'exclusiondate': '10/30/2015',
 'lastnameorbusinessname': 'Clabough',
 'firstname': 'Kenneth',
 'providertype': 'mapped from speciality',
 'exclusionauthority': None,
 'exclusionreason': 'Failure to disclose required information',
 'lastname': 'Clabough',
 'businessname': '',
 'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'TN'}
```

Comment: I think this works! I'm still verifying the results but its looking good so far! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

taking a guess because there is so much going on with your post.

```py
import csv

includes = {
    'rowid': 'rowid',
    'begindate': 'exclusiondate',
    'lastnameorbusinessname': 'lastnameorbusinessname',
    'firstname': 'firstname',
    'providertype': 'providertype',
    'exclusionauthority': 'exclusionauthority',
    'exclusionreason': 'exclusionreason',
    'lastname': 'lastname',
    'businessname': 'businessname',
    'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'exclusionstatemedicaid',
    }
result = []

with open('data.csv', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        curr_dict = {}
        for key, val in includes.items():
            curr_dict[val] = row.get(key)
        result.append(curr_dict)

with open('results.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    headers = list(includes.values())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

this uses a dictionary to map the keys from the input to the output.  the `result` dictionary looks like this:

```
{'rowid': '1',
 'exclusiondate': '9/17/2015',
 'lastnameorbusinessname': 'Bhullar-Ball',
 'firstname': 'Ramneet',
 'providertype': None,
 'exclusionauthority': None,
 'exclusionreason': None,
 'lastname': 'Bhullar-Ball',
 'businessname': '',
 'exclusionstatemedicaid': 'TN'}
```

the result `csv` looks like this:

```
rowid,exclusiondate,lastnameorbusinessname,firstname,providertype,exclusionauthority,exclusionreason,lastname,businessname,exclusionstatemedicaid
1,9/17/2015,Bhullar-Ball,Ramneet,,,,Bhullar-Ball,,TN
2,9/17/2015,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",,,,,,"Cumberland Neurology, LLC",TN
3,10/30/2015,Clabough,Kenneth,,,,Clabough,,TN
```

note that your sample input file does not contain all the field names in your desired output, thus the `None` in the dict and empty fields in the csv. if there are other keys, map them in the `includes` dictionary, the key is the input field name, value is the desired field name.

Comment: This gets me kinda close but is a step back. Your guess worked for the sample but  once I finish filling out the dictionary I get a bunch of extra fields because each file is different and many fields are being combined. eg providertype is in most files as something else so last known program or provider type, provider_type, providerspecialty, specialty etc etc. Once I add those to the includes, then a) i get a bunch of duplicate column names b) the order is wrong

Comment: if you're getting duplicates or extras then you are doing something wrong, because the code creates a csv with only the fields in the includes and in the order of the includes keys. if your csv have such random field names and you need to re-map them then provide better samples and desired output.

Comment: I provided the simplest file as a sample input but mentioned at the very top why I was doing this. I have 50+ files almost all of them are different hence why I have a dictionary file. I was at your solution hours ago and determined it wouldn't work once I filled out my dictionary. Any solution has to be able to use the full dictionary instead of a per file dictionary or else that's exactly the same as doing it by hand since I'd have to change the dictionary for every single file.